# Querying entities throws "Invalid Operation Exception" on enum field

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I was just trying some features of entity framework 5 and kendo ui. I have a following **ProductType** enum

```
public enum ProductType {
    [Description("Hazardous")]
    Hazardous,
    [Description("Non Hazardous")]
    NonHazardous
}
```

This enum type is one of the field in the **Product** Entity.

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other Fields ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Product Type is Required")]
    public ProductType ProductType {get;set;}

}
```

The ProductType column in the underlying SQL Server Database is defined as **(tinyint, not null)**.

I access list of Products in the following Controller Action of MVC

```
    public ActionResult _ProductList(int pageSize, int skip) {
        using (WorkUnit workUnit = new WorkUnit()) {
            IQueryable<Product> products = workUnit.ProductRepository.GetAllProducts()
                                                   .Include(p => p.Category);
            int total = products.Count();
            List<Product> productList = products.ToList<Product>(); //Throws InvalidOperationException
            return Json(new { total = total, data = productList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Here is the description of the InvalidOperationException that is thrown on **products.ToList()** in the above controller action.

```
The 'ProductType' property on 'Product' could not be set to a 'Byte' value. 
You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'ProductType'.
```

Any guesses why **ToList()** is throwing an **InvalidOperationException**.

Just for info, the Database existed previously, and the Entities were manually coded based on the Database as POCO's.

**Edit**
Here is the complete exception details

```
  System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The 'ProductType' property on 'Product' could not be set to a 'Byte' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'ProductType'. 
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at KendoUI_Web_Demo.Controllers.HomeController._ProductList(Int32 pageSize, Int32 skip) in d:\Practice\ASP.NET_MVC\KendoUI_Web_Demo\KendoUI_Web_Demo\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 52
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the enum type which in your case is `int` based and your database where the column is byte (tinyint) based. You can fix this by setting the correct underlying type of your enum type:

```
public enum ProductType : byte
{
...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that byte was default. But as you pointed out, and also documented here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.110).aspx) it is indeed int.